# gunicorn + SCRIPT_NAME + flask (behind nginx)

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy a gunicorn + flask app behind nginx with a path context (https://example.com/my-app)

The app runs fine locally with gunicorn + flask, setting the environment variable "SCRIPT_NAME" for the gunicorn runtime (actually a launch config in VS Code).

```
            "env": {
                "SCRIPT_NAME": "/my-app",
```

Then `request.script_name` becomes `/my-app`, as expected.

When I try to set the SCRIPT_NAME as a header in nginx

```
location /my-app/ {
                  include proxy_params;
                  proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME "/my-app";
                  proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
          }
```

I can see the
`Script-Name: /my-app` among the request.headers in the flask app

However, the `request.script_name` is empty and so all url_for(...) fail to work properly.

P.S.: I tried to set the env variable for gunicorn in the service descriptor, but in the (access) logs it does not show up. Anyways, the header solutions seems more appropriate, because it keeps the prefix in the place where I mount it into the rest of the server.

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth. I found my problem and the solution.

The SCRIPT_NAME header was overwritten by the

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix /;
```

which was hiding in the `proxy_params` include file.

Removing this prefix led to gunicorn setting the correct header in flask and flask's url_for() behaving as expected.